# Combine 2 rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

The database holds data and labels in separate rows rather than columns. How can I create a query showing the label and data on the same row? You can see the "CiscoLicense**Label**" in the AssignmentName for the lines that have the label value. And the values that say "CiscoLicenseEnabled" would be the matching value.

Query used to generate image result

```
SELECT 
    cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID, cps.Status, RowID, cpa.AssignmentName
FROM
    Orion.NPM.CustomPollerStatus cps
INNER JOIN
    Orion.NPM.CustomPollerAssignment AS [cpa] ON cpa.custompollerassignmentID = cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID
WHERE
    cpa.AssignmentName LIKE 'CiscoLicense%'
ORDER BY
    RowID, Status
```

[image: query output]

Is it possible to combine them in the same row?

If it's not possible, please let me know - I've tried partitioning a row number and joining on that, none of my attempts seem to solve the problem.

**Edit**: forgot to illustrate the desired result. The first 4 rows should return something looking like:

[image: result]

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with a MWE?

Comment: like a sample? Its hosted on an offline server but sample data is here https://thwack.solarwinds.com/products/network-performance-monitor-npm/f/forum/101624/need-undp-report-showing-labels-and-data-on-the-same-row-for-multiple-devices

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Fiddle like https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: actually I did paste raw data into the question, not an image, it was actually the text box that turned my raw data into an image. I'm not sure why it would do that instead of pasting text data

Comment: The editor doesn't convert text to image... That must be your device.

Comment: How did you get on? You have 3 answers awaiting your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate these datasets by `AssignmentName` data and join by common data in inline view

```sql
select l.col1, nl.col2, l.col2
from
    (select col1, col2 
     from Table where AssignmentName like '%label%') l inner join 
    (select col1, col2 
     from Table where AssignmentName not like '%label%') nl 
         on l.col1 = nl.col1 -- column that has same data in both rows
```

This will return only where there is a pair. Alternatively you can use Left/Right join, or both (full)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID, cps.Status, RowID, cpa.AssignmentName
   ,max( case when isnumeric( cps.Status) = 1 then cps.Status end) over( partition by RowID) as new_Status
   ,max( case when isnumeric( cps.Status) <> 1 then cps.Status end) over( partition by RowID) as new_label
 FROM Orion.NPM.CustomPollerStatus cps
 inner join Orion.NPM.CustomPollerAssignment as [cpa] on 
  cpa.custompollerassignmentID = cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID
where cpa.AssignmentName like 'CiscoLicense%'
order by RowID, Status
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation

Comment: To wit: "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." OP already tried analytical formulas, so they are aware of the topic, their only trouble is execution. What's there to explain, @DaleK ?

Comment: I wouldn't consider the other responses to be good explanations (even if they are - could be some english words arranged around some code); same as your comment, which sound more like an HR "do it for our checkmark" demand to me. So, would you be so kind to be specific to what explanation to this (apparently) transactional exchange is needed?

Comment: Dale, you are welcome to do all that if you have time and desire and want to validate yourself. I'll give you an example of a highly rated useful answer to demonstrate that your self-righteousness is not rooted in reality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server?rq=1. Personally, I don't understand your desire to micromanage but to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE yourquery
(
    CustomPollerAssignmentID    VARCHAR(512),
    Status  VARCHAR(512),
    RowID   int,
    AssignmentName  VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO yourquery 
(CustomPollerAssignmentID, Status, RowID, AssignmentName) VALUES 
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 1, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Ipservices', 1, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 2, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Ipservices eval', 2, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 3, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Ipbase', 3, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 4, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Ipbase eval', 4, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '3', 5, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Lanbase', 5, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 6, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Apcount eval', 6, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 7, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Base apcount', 7, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA'),
 ('fb1a1e57-5946-43a1-89e1-17b131c9b0c9', '1', 8, 'CiscoLicenseEnabled on switchA'),
 ('7656a43f-ba1f -487b-b060-2e8d0e850e38', 'Adder apcount', 8, 'CiscoLicenseLabel on switchA');
```

you should use `Group by`,`Max`,`Min` and `case` to get your desired result

```
select rowid,
  min(status) status ,
  max(status) LABEL,
  max(case when AssignmentName like N'%abled%' THEN  AssignmentName ELSE NULL END) 
FROM yourquery 
GROUP BY rowid
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q6oqpNz4)

transforming the above query to your query using subquery

```
select rowid,
  min(status) status ,
  max(status) LABEL,
  max(case when AssignmentName like N'%abled%' THEN  AssignmentName ELSE NULL END) 
FROM (
SELECT 
    cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID, cps.Status, RowID, cpa.AssignmentName
FROM
    Orion.NPM.CustomPollerStatus cps
INNER JOIN
    Orion.NPM.CustomPollerAssignment AS [cpa] ON cpa.custompollerassignmentID = cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID
WHERE
    cpa.AssignmentName LIKE 'CiscoLicense%'

) as yourquery
GROUP BY rowid
```

in addition you can get far better and faster result by changing your query

```
SELECT 
  RowID, 
  min(cps.Status) status, 
  max(cps.Status) Lable, 
  max(
    case when cpa.AssignmentName like N '%abled%' THEN cpa.AssignmentName ELSE NULL END
  ) AssignmentName 
FROM 
  Orion.NPM.CustomPollerStatus cps 
  INNER JOIN Orion.NPM.CustomPollerAssignment AS [cpa] ON cpa.custompollerassignmentID = cps.CustomPollerAssignmentID 
WHERE 
  cpa.AssignmentName LIKE 'CiscoLicense%' 
group by 
  RowID 
ORDER BY 
  RowID, 
  Status
```